# Jquery Validate Focus to Hidden field on invalid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jquery validate to validate hidden fields due to using typeahead (setting a hidden field on select) and rateit plugin (setting a hidden field on select)

They are validating fine and I have the error message displaying and clearing correctly.

The issue is that if one of those fields is the first invalid field it doesn't focus because the element is hidden.

Anyone know a way around this?

thanks

Comment: Well...yeah. I know it's hidden but it's related to an actual field being displayed on the form as described above. So there is a someplace to focus to validate just doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up doing it this way and it's working well. I added an attribute to my hidden inputs

Ex:

```
<input name='whatever" class="required" focusID="ID_TO_FOCUSTO" value="">
```

Then added this to validate. If it's visible it just focused to that element like normal. If not then it focuses to the ID of the attribute focusID on the hidden input.

```
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            if($(validator.errorList[0].element).is(":visible"))
            {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
            else
            {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#" + $(validator.errorList[0].element).attr("focusID")).offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It'd be nice not to put an invalid attribute into markup, but prefer to scrolling to any element nearby the `.errorList[0].element`. Nevertheless worth an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a custom rule for Typeahead field, validating the hidden field containing the id value. So if it is invalid, focus will be put on the typeahead field.

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("myCustomValidate", function() {
        //check if hidden field has a value
        return $("#hiddenFieldId").value);
    }, "You must be select a item");


$('validatorElement').validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules : {
        typeaheadElement: { myCustomValidate: true }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Did work for typeahead but ended up going with the solution below to work for both typeahead and rateit.

Comment: FYI there's a syntax error in the above code. Tried to suggest the edit but it was rejected for some reason. 
return $("#hiddenFieldId").value) should be return $("#hiddenFieldId").val()